# power query - sumifs - matrix

Tags: excel, powerquery, sumifs

i have the below table in power query.

```
╔══════════════════════╦══════════════════════╦══════════════════╗
║       Project        ║      Project 2       ║  Balance         ║
╠══════════════════════╬══════════════════════╬══════════════════╣
║ (088) GARAJ-16       ║ (084) MFK DOMODEDOVA ║     83,434.11    ║
║ (088) GARAJ-16       ║ (085) FILI RESIDENCE ║  5,936,348.56    ║
║ (085) FILI RESIDENCE ║ (084) MFK DOMODEDOVA ║ -3,516,805.40    ║
║ (085) FILI RESIDENCE ║ (088) GARAJ-16       ║ -4,436,348.56    ║
║ (084) MFK DOMODEDOVA ║ (085) FILI RESIDENCE ║  4,516,805.40    ║
║ (084) MFK DOMODEDOVA ║ (088) GARAJ-16       ║    -83,434.11    ║
╚══════════════════════╩══════════════════════╩══════════════════╝
```

the result i want to get is :

```
╔══════════════════════╦═════════════════╦══════════════════════╦══════════════════════╗
║                      ║ (088) GARAJ-16  ║ (085) FILI RESIDENCE ║ (084) MFK DOMODEDOVA ║
╠══════════════════════╬═════════════════╬══════════════════════╬══════════════════════╣
║ (088) GARAJ-16       ║  $-             ║  $1,500,000.00       ║  $-                  ║
║ (085) FILI RESIDENCE ║  $1,500,000.00  ║  $-                  ║  $1,000,000.00       ║
║ (084) MFK DOMODEDOVA ║  $-             ║  $1,000,000.00       ║  $-                  ║
╚══════════════════════╩═════════════════╩══════════════════════╩══════════════════════╝
```

this result i can get by two sumifs formulas in excel but i couldnt manage to get the result directly in power query without writing any formulas.

any ideas ?

Comment: How do you calculate the results from the input?

Comment: @MarcelBeug the formula i am using in excel is :

`=SUMIFS(Matrix[Balance Ruble];Matrix[Project];$B402;Matrix[Project 2];C$401)+SUMIFS(Matrix[Balance Ruble];Matrix[Project];C$401;Matrix[Project 2];$B402)`

Comment: I didn't ask for a formula that tells me nothing; I was wondering what the logic would be to arrive at such nicely rounded figures from not so nicely rounded Balances. If you are not able to explain, then we won't be able to help you.

Comment: It is DomodedovO, by the way. ;)

Comment: @MarcelBeug the magic is in your hands to create this result ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    #"Invoked Custom Function" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "fnButunSantiyeler", each fnButunSantiyeler([Query])),
    #"Expanded fnButunSantiyeler" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Invoked Custom Function", "fnButunSantiyeler", {"Hesap No", "santiye kodu", "Ruble Balance", "USD Balance"}, {"Hesap No", "santiye kodu", "Ruble Balance", "USD Balance"}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded fnButunSantiyeler",{"Query"}),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Removed Columns",{"santiye kodu"},#"Projects List",{"Proje Kodu"},"NewColumn",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded NewColumn" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "NewColumn", {"Proje Adi"}, {"Proje Adi.1"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Expanded NewColumn",{{"Proje Adi.1", "Karsi Proje"}}),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Renamed Columns",{"Proje Kodu", "Proje Adi", "Hesap No", "santiye kodu", "Karsi Proje", "Ruble Balance"}),
    #"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Reordered Columns", "Proje", each "(" & [Proje Kodu] & ") " &[Proje Adi]),
    #"Added Custom3" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom2", "Karsi Proje.1", each "(" & [santiye kodu] & ") " & [Karsi Proje]),
    #"Reordered Columns1" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Added Custom3",{"Karsi Proje.1", "Proje", "Proje Kodu", "Proje Adi", "Hesap No",  "santiye kodu", "Karsi Proje", "Ruble Balance"}),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Reordered Columns1",{"Proje Kodu", "Proje Adi", "santiye kodu", "Karsi Proje"}),
    #"Renamed Columns1" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Columns1",{{"Karsi Proje.1", "Karsi Proje"}}),
    #"Reordered Columns2" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Renamed Columns1",{"Proje", "Karsi Proje", "Ruble Balance"}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Reordered Columns2", {"Proje", "Karsi Proje", "Hesap No"}, {{"Ruble Balance", each List.Sum([Ruble Balance]), type number}}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Grouped Rows", each [Karsi Proje] <> null),
    #"Added Conditional Column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "Custom", each if [Hesap No] = "331" then [Proje]&"xxx"&[Karsi Proje] else if [Hesap No] = "131" then [Karsi Proje]&"xxx"&[Proje] else null ),
    #"Grouped Rows1" = Table.Group(#"Added Conditional Column", {"Custom"}, {{"sum", each List.Sum([Ruble Balance]), type number}}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Grouped Rows1","Custom",Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("xxx", QuoteStyle.Csv),{"Custom.1", "Custom.2"}),
    #"Rounded Off" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"sum", each Number.Round(_, 2), type number}}),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Rounded Off",{{"Custom.2", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Sorted Rows", List.Distinct(#"Sorted Rows"[Custom.2]), "Custom.2", "sum", List.Sum)
in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```

i have solved it in another way, i put it here, maybe it may help to someone else...

Answer (score 0):

This code gives the result you are looking for.

```
let
    Source = Table1,
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(Source,{"Project", "Project 2"},Source,{"Project 2", "Project"},"NewColumn",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded NewColumn" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "NewColumn", {"Balance"}, {"NewColumn.Balance"}),
    #"Inserted Addition" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded NewColumn", "Inserted Addition", each [Balance] + [NewColumn.Balance], type number),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Inserted Addition",{"Balance", "NewColumn.Balance"}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Removed Columns", List.Sort(List.Distinct(#"Removed Columns"[Project]),1), "Project", "Inserted Addition"),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Pivoted Column",{{"Project 2", Order.Descending}})
in
    #"Sorted Rows"
```

Comment: thank you for your time and support. but still i couldnt get the result i wanted... please find the source file [here](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/8gHH/ajMnVyeoR)

Comment: @UmutK Unfortunately we haven't learned magic of reading someone else's thoughts. So unless you clearly explain how you want calculations to be done, we won't be able to help. And, if you care, you've got a hell of a typos in location names in your file.

Comment: @Eugene isn't it really clear to understand what i want from the tables i wrote ? never mind the locations' names )))

Comment: @UmutK I've looked at your source  file, but it seems to me more like a result example.